# How can I query for entries that have one of two Lightswitch fields enabled?

Tags: templating, elementcriteriamodel, lightswitch

I have two Lightswitch fields – `lightswitchA` and `lightswitchB` – and I need to pull all entries in a certain section, that have *one or both* of these fields enabled.

Is it possible to execute such a query with a standard ElementCriteriaModel, or do I need to construct a custom query? If I need to construct a custom query, how would that look (in a template, not a plugin)?

I also need to paginate the results, using the `{% paginate %}` tag.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can’t do that natively use the field handle as an attribute (I might be wrong) but you could try it with the search parameter?

Comment: @JoshAngell Thanks – as it happens, carlcs' answer solved this one for me nicely, but I'd love to see a way to do it using search, too, if you ever get the chance to type it out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Craft 3

Thanks to the `where()` function this has become easy in Craft 3.

```
{% set query = craft.entries.where([
    'or',
    {'field_lightswitchA': 1},
    {'field_lightswitchB': 1},
]) %}
```

### Craft 2

Custom field parameters are being added with and-logic, so you'd indeed have to
do it from PHP with custom dbCommands.

You could either approach it with converting a criteria model to a dbCommand object using the `buildElementsQuery` method, or you listen for `elements.buildElementsQuery` events and modify the dbCommand if the criteria model meets certain conditions.

```
craft()->on('elements.buildElementsQuery', function(Event $event) {
    $criteria = $event->params['criteria'];
    $dbCommand = $event->params['query'];

    if (isset($criteria->or_lightswitchA) && isset($criteria->or_lightswitchB)) {
        $params = array(
            ':lightswitchA_value' => $criteria->or_lightswitchA,
            ':lightswitchB_value' => $criteria->or_lightswitchB,
        );

        $conditions = array('or',
            'content.field_lightswitchA=:lightswitchA_value',
            'content.field_lightswitchB=:lightswitchB_value',
        );

        $dbCommand->andWhere($conditions, $params);
    }
});
```

Here's how you'd trigger that listener from your criteria model in Twig.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    or_lightswitchA: 1,
    or_lightswitchB: 1,
}) %}
```

Here's example code for the `buildElementsQuery` approach, the problem with this is that
once you've converted to dbCommands you can't go back to a criteria model (which would be
necessary to use the result with Craft's `paginate` tag for example).

```
public function myCustomCriteria($criteria, $lightswitchA_value, $lightswitchB_value)
{
    $dbCommand = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);

    $params = array(
        ':lightswitchA_value' => $lightswitchA_value,
        ':lightswitchB_value' => $lightswitchB_value,
    );

    $conditions = array('or',
        'content.field_lightswitchA=:lightswitchA_value',
        'content.field_lightswitchB=:lightswitchB_value',
    );

    $dbCommand->andWhere($conditions, $params);

    $results = $dbCommand->queryAll();

    return EntryModel::populateModels($results);
}
```

Comment: carlcs, you're a champ. I've yet to test this (will do really soon), but A+ answer – thanks a lot!

Comment: I do actually need to paginate the results, btw – so I'll be going with the event approach.

Comment: I had to test if the two attributes were actually set for the `$criteria` object, but other than that, this worked like a charm. I did a minor edit to your answer to reflect what actually worked for me in the end. Thanks again!