# How do I filter by multiple Smart Map addresses?

Tags: plugin-smartmap

I have profiles (Users) that can have multiple addresses (currently two Smart Map fields called `profileAddress1` and `profileAddress2`).

I know how to filter by a single address:

```
{% set results = craft.users({
    group: 'profiles',
    profileAddress1: {
        target: 'Cologne',
        range: 20
    }
}) %}
```

How would I search across both fields? So if a profile had two addresses – one in Cologne and one in Munich – it should show up in the results in both search cases (Cologne and Munich).

Is that even possible?

Comment: [Carl's answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/15159/45) is spot on. You can only do a proximity search for one address field at a time. However, the workaround is to **perform two separate queries, and merge together the resulting entry ids.** Carl's answer (and linked references) describes the technique very well.

Comment: @LindseyD thanks for the hint. Unfortunately I have trouble making clean searches for the separate address fields. Querying only for the `profileAddress2` field returns results whose `profileAddress2` field is empty. It seems like it’s querying for `profileAddress1` instead. Other results that should show up (because they have a matching address set in `profileAddress2` won’t show up. Is that maybe a bug in the SQL query or something? It’s driving me crazy :)

Comment: Hmm, it might be a bug... email support@doublesecretagency.com, and we can sort it out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to setup two criteria models, one for each Smart Map field, and query for the element IDs. Merge these IDs and have a 3rd criteria model where you pass in the IDs to the `id` parameter.

See this question for example code:

> [Complex logic on a ElementCriteriaModel parameter?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1948/complex-logic-on-a-elementcriteriamodel-parameter)

Here's a blog post describing the technique in details:

> [Manipulating Craft's ElementCriteriaModel objects with Twig](https://webstoemp.com/blog/manipulating-craft-elementcriteriamodel-with-twig/)

If you need better performance, have a look at the custom Yii query builder code I posted here:

> [How can I query for entries that have one of two Lightswitch fields enabled?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14618/how-can-i-query-for-entries-that-have-one-of-two-lightswitch-fields-enabled)

Comment: Beat me to it... and with a perfect answer! :)

Comment: Thanks for the nudge into the right direction! Especially the blog post helps a lot.

Comment: Do you have any clue how this would work using the [element api plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI)?

Comment: You can setup the criteria models in the transformer, have a look at this answer to get an idea of this http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/14691/125